Infinix S4 refusing to hard reset
My Infinix S4 is refusing to boot/on completely whenever I try to turn it on. It just shows Infinix and then turns off and then shows Infinix again and then turns off. It keeps doing that way till the battery is dead. When I try to do it hard reset it tells me

failed to format/cache: permission denied

I have tried doing hand flashing but it keeps telling me

failed to format/cache : permission denied


It looks like your /cache partition is corrupted, sufficiently thoroughly that the OS can't format it. What was done on the device before this started? Were you trying to flash it, or clear the cache?
